# Cómo influye el parametro 'arr' en el parámetro 'func' en este caso?

Tags: funciones, while

Me gustaría poder llegar a entender al 100% la lógica de este código:

```
    function dropElements(arr, func) {
      while(!func(arr[0])) {
        arr.shift() }
        return arr
    }

    console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], (x) => {return x >= 2; }));

//Returns [2, 3, 4]
```

Me atasco en la parte del `(!func(arr[0]))`. Veo que dice que 'si el número del parámetro func no coincide con el del index 0 del array, haz un arr.shift(), es decir, suprímelo'.

Lo que no entiendo es por qué func es 2. Veo que func ejecuta una lógica que devuelve la propia función cuando esta es mayor o igual que 2, pero no que func sea igual a 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el ejemplo, `dropElements` es una función que recibe por argumento un *array* y una función.
La función que pasamos por parámetro recibe un *number* y devuelve un *boolean*. Exactamente, devuelve si el número por parámetro es mayor o igual que `2`.

Dentro de `dropElements`, se va a iterar sobre el *array* con la condición de que el primer elemento del *array* cumpla con la condición de la función que pasamos por parámetro.

Análogamente, podríamos ecribir la función así

```
function dropElements(arr) {
    while(! (arr[0] >= 2)) { // o arr[0] < 2
        arr.shift() 
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Pero la condición en el `while` viene dada como parámetro en forma de función, de modo que es variable.

```
function embed(fn) {
    console.log('PRE');
    fn();
    console.log('POST');
}

function greet() {
    console.log('Hello');
}

embed(greet);
// PRE
// Hello
// POST
```

Aquí vemos cómo podemos pasar una función por parámetro.
En tu ejemplo, se pasa por parámetro una función anónima, sin nombre. Y, en concreto, usando la sintaxis de las lambdas.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
dropElements(arr, function(x) {
    return x >= 2;
});
dropElements(arr, (x) => {
    return x >= 2;
});
dropElements(arr, (x) => x >= 2);
dropElements(arr, x => x >= 2);
```

Estas cuatro llamadas son totalmente equivalentes. Te dejo aquí [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) de las *lambas* (o *arrow functions* o funciones flecha).

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Bueno, no me cansaré de decir que la comunidad española de StackOverflow es maravillosa.Mil gracias, además de muy bien explicado. Me ha quedado mucho más claro entender, y además me has pasado enlaces interesantes. Ojalá y algún día sepa tanto como para poder ayudarte yo a tí. Un saludo!

Comment: Seguro que puedes ayudarme en muchísimas cosas. Cada uno es maestro en ciertos temas, solo debemos procurar compartir entre todos para crecer todxs juntxs.

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente, la función `dropElements` recibe dos parámetros un array y un `callback`.

> Callback una función que se pasa a otra función como un argumento, que
>   luego se invoca dentro de la función externa(en este caso `dropElements`) para completar algún tipo
>   de rutina o acción

Y lo que hace el bucle `while` es evaluar mientras el valor devuelto por el `func` pasandole siempre el primer elemento del array `func(arr[0])` se evalúa a `false` se borra el primer elemento usando el método `shift` que borra el primer elemento del array. En este caso es el mismo que el que `arr[0]`.

```
while(!func(arr[0])){} // la negeación evalua el si el valor es falsy
while(func(arr[0]) === false ){} // seria equivalente
```

Para que lo veas más claro tu código simplificado sería así.

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
   // func es la referencia a la funcion esMayorOIgualQue2
    while(!func(arr[0])) { // aqui se ejecuta con el primer elemento esMayorOIgualQue2(1)
      arr.shift() 
    }
    return arr;
}

function esMayorOIgualQue2(numero) {
  return numero >= 2;
}

console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], esMayorOIgualQue2));
```

Comment: Puedes leer el comentario que le he puesto a @VRoxa, arriba. Opino justo lo mismo con tu comentario. Os agradezco de verdad que me ayudeis. En la comunidad inglesa de StackOverflow el trato ha sido un poco malo, pero aquí, en español, el trato es magnífico. Un saludo y gracias!